# Eclipse: Use background color instead of outline for matching bracket

Tags: eclipse

Does anybody know how to set the background color of matching brackets to yellow instead of using a grey outline? I want to do this to be consistent with NetBeans IDE and EditPad Pro.

Comment: I've looked. I'm not sure it's possible, but not confident enough to put it in an answer.

Comment: @Craige Pretty sure there is no such option as of Luna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse Version: 3.4.0 (Ganymede). I went to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor

I changed the 'Matching brackets highlight' to yellow, but it only changed the color of the outline, *not the background*. It's hard to see just that yellow outline on a white background. Looking at these options though, I don't see how it would be possible to get the highlight you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Window menu, Preferences option, the select the language you want to change it for in the left column (e.g. C/C++, Java, etc), then choose Editor, and select the top option of the middle frame, change to whatever color you want.
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use a background color instead of an outline?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, unfortunately.  I didn't realize that's what you were asking for, so apologies.  I was even looking at syntax highlighting to see if you could do something with the color of the braces themselves, but it looks like no dice.

Comment: @George check out something [like this](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/) I don't know if it would have that feature.

Comment: @jonsca it does let you do full highlighting on closing brackets! however its overridden all my other color settings which is annoying...so i still need to mess around with it

Answer (score 3):

The answers listed (   Window > Preferences > Java > Editor ) are accurate for the question.  But if your goal is to find ways to visually see everything inside of braces, here are a couple of more ways you can do this:

**Move cursor to the opposite brace**:  Ctrl-Shift-P moves the cursor to the opposite brace 
If you start somewhere in the middle of a section, this will toggle among three points, the beginning brace and the ending brace and where the cursor started. This works for parentheses also.

**Highlight the contents of the braces:**  double click just to the right of the open, or left of the closing brace.  The area is highlighted. At this point you can also copy to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Check the image where you need to change "Selection background color" and "Selection Foreground color" to highlight the background of the selected code.
[image]